# Stop Rails 3.2 from rendering both html.erb and js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm calling an action, `Home#index`, to an empty action in `HomeController`.

The page loads fine in HTML, which is what I expect (rendering `home/index.html.erb`, but then it also loads the corresponding js for that action as well, arriving some 100ms after (rendering `home/index.js.erb`). How can I stop this? I only want the javascript response when I call for it, not through an HTTP GET request.

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js # Nothing changes whether I have this or not

  def index
    respond_to do |format| # Nothing changes whether I have this or not
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Ajaxtest::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb.</p>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#content").html("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, yo non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.");
document.title = "AJAX loaded";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `format.html` from the `respond_to` block in the controller.

Comment: Doing that makes it not respond to html via an HTTP GET request. Thanks for the suggestion though!